# Getting ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node-fetch

```
import {Router} from 'express'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const tasks=Router()

tasks.get('/', async (req,res) => {
const response= fetch('https://dummy-api')
res.json(response)
})
```

I am getting the error,ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID . Adding process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=1 solved the issue but its not secure to use. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Is the API you calling under your control? If not then you cant do anything about it. `https://dummy-api` is not a valid FQDN. Your censoring makes it hard to help you correctly.

Comment: The original api that I am using is a valid one.Its not the one that I mentioned here. I cannot make any changes to the api / response as such.